# InteliJ Shortcut Maven clean install

Tags: intellij-idea

I try to find a way to do the following steps in InteliJ by using only keyboard:

1. alt+ F1 --> F
2. Currently I'm clicking CTRL + Left Mouse to choose clean and install.

Is there a way to do this just by using the keyboard?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may assign shortcuts to "clean" and "install" actions and use them.

Comment: I would like to build in the places where my context is right now.
The shortcut is always only for a specific context, isn't it?
So I'm looking for a global setting.

Comment: What do you mean by context?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for existing shourtcut or tring to add a new one on intellij, the best thing to do is to check the key map.

the KeyMap is located in `File|Settings` for windows and linux or `IntelliJ IDEA|Preferences` for macOS (`Ctrl+alt+S` is good too) and then look for the KeyMap tab and search "maven".

[image: add shourtcuts]